# Indexing image information extracted from images

Tags: lucene

I want to index histogram information from images with Lucene.
I need to know what Lucene class I should modify to tell Lucene that it shouldn't read file contents (clearly there wouldn't be anything readable inside an image file) BUT it should use my class that extracts histogram info and returns an array of numbers (or it can be whatever structure that lucene could index).

**Example**: a histogram for an example image looks like this **100 150 71** 46.

I am searching for an image that has **100 150 71** 250. 
I want Lucene to return the example image, cause it has those 3 colors same. Will this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Lucene itself works only with text, so you should first extract your numbers and then add document with text "100 150 71 46".

You should also use analyzer that doesn't remove numbers. For example, if you want to search histograms with *any* of specified numbers (regardless of their order), you can use [StandardAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html). And if you care about order, take a look at [KeywordAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/KeywordAnalyzer.html) and specify queries like this:

```
100 150 71*
```

However, Lucene doesn't seem to be a good choice for such type of data, so also consider other kinds of storage, specifically, based on [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: I have one more question. You know, it would be a nonsense to search regardless of the order of the numbers, because that image wouldn't be similar to the one Im looking for. But what do you think if I automatically searched for intervals <-10;+10> of these numbers e.g. 101 150 71 46, 102 150 etc.. Well that would give quite a lot of combinations considering that I am extracting 8 numbers.